# Reports Templates in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, report

I have 4 reports, but note that 2 of them are similar, which changes from one to the other is the header or content.
Note that headers 1 and 2 have equal but different contents.
3 e 4 too.
But note that 1 and 3 have the same content. And 2 and 4 also.

Question: How can I have some report templates, ie, I wanted to minimize the amount of form reports and edit in one or at most two reports?

In case 1 and 3 are detailed contents, and 2 and 4 are summaries. So in the end I could only have 2 reports: 1 and 2.

Suggestions?

[image]

Comment: If I am needing a report that is similar to another, I just copy that report and paste it.  Then make the necessary changes to it.

Comment: But if make changes constantly?

Comment: If the reports are that similar you could just define one report and change the things that need to change on the fly.